# "Misspelled" vs. "Mistyped"

Tags: difference, word-difference

If I enter a letter incorrectly when typing, for example v**a**getable instead of v**e**getable, then "a" is a misspelled letter or mistyped letter?

What is the difference in general?

Comment: Did you type it?

Comment: @user3169 yes its typed in computer

Comment: You need to edit your question with that detail.

Comment: I think 'misspelled' implies that you didn't know the correct spelling. 'Mistyped' implies what happened: you know the spelling, but there was an error somewhere between your brain and your fingers.

Comment: @snailboat if you have the same answer you can enter it as answer or else enter the correct answer so we get the difference!

Comment: I misspell lots of words all the time. I \*mispell them, my knowing the correct spelling notwithstanding.

Comment: @snailboat I also said the same! if you know that is incorrect, why you don't post the correct answer please ? that way people won't vote the only promising comment up. Or maybe you just know it is incorrect but don't know the correct one!

Comment: @snailboat - I would've characterized the difference in the same way jamesqf did, although I can see how opinions might defer ;^)

Comment: It's okay—I replaced my grumbling with an upvote.  The question has been answered, we can move on :-)

Answer (score 4):

Let's take a practical example - your screen name, 'Ahmad'.

Say I go to enter it into a document, but at the end of my typing the result is 'Ahmed'. There are two possible causes:

1. I know that the name is spelt A-h-m-a-d, but have made a mistake during the transfer from brain to screen (whether through inattention, fat fingers, etc.). This is mistyping.
2. I do not know that the name is spelt A-h-m-a-d. Instead, I think it is spelt A-h-m-e-d. I have typed it perfectly, but the mistake was made before I started. This is misspelling.

Note that that is the 'technical' difference. In practice, people will use 'mispelled' in place of 'mistyped' quite often. Working out where the mistake actually took place (in their head, or from their hands) is the key to knowing which term is actually correct.

Comment: Thanks, I think in many nation they spell my name *Ahmed*, then you won't be such wrong! However, It's originally an Arabic name and in Arabic they pronounce it *Ahmad* as in Persian. Here, you maybe just misthought or mispronounced which lead to misspelled!

Comment: @Damien Good answer

Comment: I usually misprint chars while typing. I do sometimes misspell them too.